# Java WebService technologies

Tags: java, web-services

I'm begining with java web services.  And I'm quite lost.

If I have good undersdood there are two types of architecture

- soap web services
- restfull web services

But after ...

Is it right to say that there are framework apis to help building web services and that

- JAX-WS

is one of those apis ?

I know the reference implementation of jax-ws is

- metro

And I suppose it is bundled with java 6 and so glassfish 3.1.

But

- axis2

Is it an api ?  An implementation of jax-ws ?

Which others apis and implementations are existing ?
And if i'm working with weblogic 10.3.5 ?

Now, if I take the problem on the other side.

I have to consume a web service.  What do I have to know about it ?

I suppose I have to know if it is soap or rest, but after ?

Answer (score 1):

O boy, this takes a book to explain but very high level:

Java EE defines a whole bunch of API's which are basically only interfaces, no implementations. **JAX-WS** is the API for SOAP-based webservices while **JAX-RS** is the API for REST-based services.

The actual implementation that is used depends on your java EE container, there are many. Metro is the implementation bundled with the glassfish EE server, jboss AS uses JBossWS. Axis is yet another implementation that supports JAX-WS (and possibly JAX-RS, haven't checked). There is also CXF and many others...

REST is easier to understand because it is very lightweight, however SOAP is the industry standard because there are a lot of standardized features (google WS-*) and it has a descriptor in the form of WSDL (WADL for REST just isn't there yet). The descriptor (generated automatically by JAX-WS) describes to the client how the webservice should be invoked and works cross-technology. It is trivial to import a WSDL generated by java in .NET for example (though if you're up to it you should google Web Services Interoperability, aka WS-I).

Java provides a utility called wsimport that allows you to generate a fully working java client from a WSDL.

But really, the basic nature of your question indicates that you have not read up on anything EE related or are even familiar with generic webservice technology which is slightly surprising since you are apparently using a weblogic server. You have a **lot** of reading ahead of you.

Comment: Thanks.  I know I have lot of work ...  Basically java is simple.  But it is not always easy to know and understand all the underlying technologies.  And for web services (I have read lot of things on internet) I find it's not easy to make the differences between api and implementation.  On some readings, they are not speaking of metro as the jax-ws ri of jax-ws but simply jax-ws !

Comment: You shouldn't have to know what implementation you use, all tutorials and all your work should be based solely on the API. The implementation is immaterial. Java is indeed rather simple (though it has a lot of very interesting quirks) but the ecosystem built on it (especially for industries) is immense and impressively well designed (in general).

Comment: Start with the basics: XML Schema, WSDL, SOAP, WS-I, WS-*, JAX-WS. In that order.

Comment: Just another question.  JAX-WS 2.0 is jsr 224.  But there is now a maintenance release 4.  So JAX-WS 2.2.  On the other hand, jsr 224 is part of java ee 5 and java se 6.  So how do I know which version of jax-ws is bundled with ?  Same question with JAX-WS RI.  Latest version is 2.2.8.

Comment: That depends on the EE version, EE 7 was just released an EE 6 is pretty standard in most AS. Even then you will have to check per AS and see what they bundle. There is usually nothing stopping you from plugging in newer/alternate versions, so if you really want the metro implementation, you can probably get it running on the jboss as without much trouble.